# How to detect client language settings in ASP?

Tags: asp-classic, locale

ALL,
What I mean is when I type, for example, www.gmail.com and my computer default langauge is Russian I see Russian text, and when my computer default language is English I see an English text.

Can I do that with ASP?

Thank you.

Comment: I found this: http://networkprogramming.wordpress.com/2006/06/02/resource-files-for-classic-asp/ but trying to use I am getting error on page...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Accept-Language](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4) header value:

```
Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"];
```

or

```
Request.Headers["accept-language"];
```

result looks something like `en-US,en;q=0.8`

the first segment (before the `;`) is a comma separated list of [language identifiers](http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html) ordered by preference.

Comment: Is this .NET solution? Thank you.

Comment: Yes it is .NET...for asp classic use `Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE")` (documentation: [Request.ServerVariables Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525396(v=vs.90).aspx), [IIS Server Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602(v=vs.90).aspx))

Comment: Ok, thx. But I presume it is read-only, correct? How do I set the language?

Comment: It is read-only because it's sent via the client's web browser and the language is specified usually at the operating system level.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called localization, you can do that using resource files, check here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228208.aspx

Comment: Hi, The site is running Classic ASP and not .NET. Is it possible? Also is there a way to SET the language globally? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Request.UserLanguages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userlanguages.aspx) will contain an ordered list of the culture preferences set in the client browser